# Compiling a document twice with different names

Tags: compiling

I have a .tex document called, let's say, "filename", in which solutions are shown or not depending on the value of a counter.

Is it possible to add commands in the document so that it is compiled twice to a PDF, once with solutions and the PDF named "filename-solution" and once without solutions with the PDF named "filename". pdflatex must be used for compilation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TeX uses \jobname to create not only the PDF, but also the log, aux, toc etc.  It can be read, but not changed (the log file is already open).  If you want more than one output file, you need to run some sort of script.

Comment: You might create two different "driver" files, each one with the settings for one of the outputs you want. The only other thing these have in them is an input for the common data file, your "filename".  The user documentation for the AMS document classes is constructed this way, for four outputs:  https://ctan.org/pkg/amscls-doc

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using optional.sty. The documentation describes just such a usage style, with a single file having its natural name plus a sym-link alias. Then the `\jobname` is used to enable or disable portions of the document based on their tagging.

```
% this file is named both filename and filename-solution using symlinks
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage[\jobname]{optional}
. . .
\opt{filename-solution}{The ultimate answer is 42}
. . .
```